# Can I have nodereferences with thumbnails in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, cck

Can I have nodereferences with thumbnails? By default I only get title+link.

Answer (score 1):

I have not read through them, but here are two discussions from drupal.org on that topic that should get you started:

- http://drupal.org/node/358857
- http://drupal.org/node/644502